# Tune nodejs + expressjs to handle many concurrent requests

Tags: node.js

How do I tune nodejs (6.1.0) and expressjs (4.13.4) to handle a large number of concurrent connections.

To demonstrate that express can handle many connections I wrote the following javascript:

```
var Q = require('q');
var needle = require('needle');
var logger = require('log4js').getLogger("deleteme");

var batches = 2;
var batchSize = 200;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

var server = app.listen(8001);


var requestBatches = [];
for(var batchIndex = 0; batchIndex < batches; ++batchIndex) {
  const thisBatch = batchIndex;
  requestBatches.push(Q.delay(batchIndex * 1000 + 1).then(function() {
    var requests = [];
    var errors = 0;
    for( var queryIndex = 0; queryIndex < batchSize; ++queryIndex) {
      requests.push( Q.nfcall(needle.get, "http://localhost:8001/", {timeout: 1000}).catch(function(error) {
        logger.error("Error: ", error.message);
        ++errors;
        throw error;
      }))

    }
    return Q.allSettled(requests).then(function() {
      if(errors) {
        logger.error("Batch: ", thisBatch, " failed ", errors, "/", batchSize)
      } else {
        logger.info("Batch: ", thisBatch, " all success")
      }
    })


  }));


}


Q.allSettled(requestBatches).finally(function() {
  logger.info("all done");
  server.close();
});
```

All this basically does is starts a server on port 8001, send several batches of connections at it, calculate the success rate for batches, and report the result.

Right now I am pouncing on the server with 200 connections, I would expect nodejs to slow down the responses but instead I get connection disconnects.

It varies run to run, sometimes I have 2 connection resets, sometimes I have a ton.  Sometimes I have socket hangups.

What can I do to tune expressjs and nodejs to handle more concurrent connections?

Sample result:

```
[2016-11-14 14:07:58.186] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:07:58.385] [ERROR] deleteme - Batch:  0  failed  1 / 200
[2016-11-14 14:07:59.280] [INFO] deleteme - Batch:  1  all success
[2016-11-14 14:07:59.281] [INFO] deleteme - all done
```

With a great many failures:

```
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.544] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.547] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.548] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.548] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.548] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.549] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.550] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.550] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.551] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.551] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.551] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.551] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.552] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.552] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.552] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.552] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.553] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.553] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.553] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.554] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.554] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.554] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:54.745] [ERROR] deleteme - Batch:  0  failed  22 / 200
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.501] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.501] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.502] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.502] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.502] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.503] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.503] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.503] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.504] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.505] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.505] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.506] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.506] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.506] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.506] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.507] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.510] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.510] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.510] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.510] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.510] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.511] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.511] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.511] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.512] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.512] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.512] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.512] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.513] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.513] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.514] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.514] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.514] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.514] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.515] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.515] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.515] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.516] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.516] [ERROR] deleteme - Error:  connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:8001
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.627] [ERROR] deleteme - Batch:  1  failed  39 / 200
[2016-11-14 14:09:55.627] [INFO] deleteme - all done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to run the server as a separate process, that might fix the ECONNRESET error.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here but what i tried is to run 10,000 request in a loop without any error.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var i = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
  i++;
  console.log(i);
});

var server = app.listen(8001);
```

test.js

```
var request = require('request');

console.time('10000 requests');
var j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    request('http://127.0.0.1:8001', function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
        if (j > 9998) console.timeEnd('10000 requests');
        j++;
    });
}
```

it takes about 9956ms on my pc and no error at all

Comment: I ran your files on Ubuntu 14.04 and MacOS.  Both have a large number of failures.  See the number of "undefined" lines below.

michaelpower@local-ic:~$ node testServer.js | wc -l &
[1] 26998
michaelpower@local-ic:~$ node testBatch.js | sort | uniq -c
      1 10000 requests: 6505.237ms
   4084 hello world
   5916 undefined
michaelpower@local-ic:~$ pkill node 
4084

Comment: @dodtsair I ran it 3 times on my windows 10 PC and no error at all. That's weird. Did you run them as separate processes?

Comment: You didn't run exactly the code I have written since you get different output. Can you try my code as it is?

Comment: I copied and pasted the contents of your files and ran node server.js & node test.js.  There was a big bunch of failures in front which might be explained by the time it takes express to start, then it ran fine for a bit, then a ton of Error: This socket is closed

Comment: I tried it previously on windows 10 without any issue and now i have just tried it on my ubuntu 16.04 server again without any issue. Can you describe **a big bunch of failure**? I would recommend running the express app first in its own terminal window, wait a second or two and in another window run the test. But i tried `node server.js & node test.js` and it works just fine on both windows and ubuntu. Can you show a screenshot of the terminal so i can see what errors you are getting?

Comment: I think I am hitting the max open files of the server.js process.  Better at identifying these limits in Linux then I am in OSX.  

server.js spits out repeatedly:
Error: accept EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:949:11)
    at TCP.onconnection (net.js:1435:24)


test.js spits out repeatedly

Comment: { Error: connect ENFILE 127.0.0.1:8001 - Local (undefined:undefined)
....

Answer (score 0):

Use as many Async calls as possible, don't use Sync unless its really required.